# Partitioning by range columns unexpected behavior

Tags: mysql, partitioning, data-partitioning

I have MySQL table partitioned by range columns (c_id and created_at)
and I created 2 partitions:

1. logs_1_2020 (c_id less than 2 and created less than 2021-01-01 00:00:00)
2. logs_1_2021 (c_id less than 2 and created less than 2022-01-01 00:00:00)

When I run

```
INSERT INTO example_log_table (c_id, data, created)
    VALUES (1, 'test', '2021-10-24 18:16:08')
```

I'm supposed to find the result stored in logs_1_2021, but I was shocked when I found her in logs_1_2020.

Does anyone have an explanation for that?

This table SQL generator:

```
CREATE TABLE example_log_table (
                        id int auto_increment ,
                        c_id int,
                        data TEXT NOT NULL,
                        created DATETIME NOT NULL,
                        primary key (id,c_id,created)
) PARTITION BY RANGE columns (c_id,created)(
    PARTITION logs_1_2020 VALUES LESS THAN  (2,'2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
    PARTITION logs_1_2021 VALUES LESS THAN  (2,'2022-01-01 00:00:00')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot for Is there a way to make Mysql insert data into partition based on column values not tuple comparison
I decide to make my partitions like that :

```
        PARTITION logs_1_2020 VALUES LESS THAN  (1,'2021-01-01'),
        PARTITION logs_2_2020 VALUES LESS THAN  (2,'2021-01-01'),
        PARTITION logs_2_2021 VALUES LESS THAN  (2,'2022-01-01')
```

And at insertion i'm insert with exact first parameter to make Mysql compare the second parameter is less or not.

So when run :

```
INSERT INTO example_log_table (c_id, created) VALUES (2, '2021-10-21')
```

**Will be inserted at logs_2_2021 because c_id is matched and created is less than created at second row**

Answer (score 0):

When you use multiple columns as your partitioning key, the placement is based on tuple comparison. You can test if a tuple is less than another tuple this way (MySQL 8.0):

```
select row(1, '2021-10-24 18:16:08') < row(2, '2021-01-01 00:00:00');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| row(1, '2021-10-24 18:16:08') < row(2, '2021-01-01 00:00:00') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             1 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The rules for tuple inequality comparison are tricky. I suggest you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-columns-range.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_less-than carefully.

> For row comparisons, `(a, b) < (x, y)` is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> (a < x) OR ((a = x) AND (b < y))
> ```

In this case, `1` is less than `2`, so the tuple you inserted is less than the tuple that defines the upper bound of partition `logs_1_2020`.

You can also think about how the data would be sorted if you were to query a set of rows with `ORDER BY c_id,created`. It would sort by `c_id` first, and then only in cases of ties on `c_id` it would sort the ties by `created`.

Comment: WOW it's using tuple comparison !
Is there a way to make it insert data into partition based on column values ?

Example: i want "logs_1_2021" partition has all data for c_id less than 2 and created less than "2022-01-01 00:00:00"

Comment: In the PostgreSQL when i'm using  PARTITION BY RANGE (c_id, created_at)
and  created partition FOR VALUES FROM (1, '2020-01-01 00:00:00') TO (1, '2021-01-01 00:00:00'') and other one FOR VALUES FROM (1, '2021-01-01 00:00:00') TO (1, '2022-01-01 00:00:00'')
when try to insert (1,'2021-10-01 00:00:00') will inserted at second partition not other because this partition created for those values 
i need to make this behavior at Mysql

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some good reason for that Partitioning, Drop it and change the indexes to

```
PRIMARY KEY(c_id, created, id),
INDEX(id)
```

If you expect to have lots of data and wish do delete "old data", the `PARTITION BY RANGE` over just `created`; this facilitates periodic `DROP PARTITION`.  And the two indexes above are still valid and useful.