# How is MySQL's range columns partitioning implemented?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I'm curious in how is MySQL implemented it's range columns partitioning, especially in how MySQL extracts the values from SQL, to compare with partition values range.

For example, create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a INT, b INT, c INT)
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(a, b) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (10, 10),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (10, 15),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (20, 20),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE, MAXVALUE),
)
```

When provided with a query with complex filters like `SELECT * FROM t WHERE a < 10 AND b > 10`, MySQL should scan only partition p1; when provided with `SELECT * FROM t WHERE a < 10 AND b > 100`, partitions p0 and p1 are scanned.

It's clearly we can't naively break the filter into sub expressions and run the partition selection each separately. For example, we can't break `a < 10 AND b > 10` into `a < 10` and `b > 10`, compare them with ranges `(10, 10), (10, 15), (20, 20), (MAXVALUE, MAXVALUE)`, find partitions each, then joins the result.

> PS: This often cause [misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69698702/partitioning-by-range-columns-unexpected-behavior) of partition selection.

Instead, we have to use **both** `a` and `b` as a tuple `(a, b)` to compare with partition ranges. However, it seems very hard to extract their values to form the tuple from SQL filters mixed with sub-queries, joins and complex logical operations like `a < 10 AND (a < 20 OR b < 20) OR b > 100`. I can't help wondering how MySQL implemented it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your interpretation of the ranges is mistaken.

Let's switch to lastname and firstname instead of numbers.  Then, thinking of a list of people sorted by last and first:

```
('James', 'Rick') comes after  ('James', 'Adam')
('James', 'Rick') comes before ('James', 'Zack')
```

and also

```
('Smith', '...') comes after ('James', '...')
```

regardless of firstname.

In other words, x comes after y if and only if

```
x.lastname >= y.lastname
    AND ( x.lastname > y.lastname OR
          x.firstname > y.firstname )
```

or, equivalently,

```
x.lastname > y.lastname
    OR ( x.lastname = y.lastname AND
         x.firstname > y.firstname )
```

It does not simply test each column separately.

This is also the way that

```
ORDER BY lastname, firstname
```

works.

What is the goal of the table??  There is likely to be *no* performance advantage in Partitioning with tuples.

To find out whether the tuples are handled efficiently, simply provide a `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and see what the "Partitions" column says.

Comment: yes, we can't simply test each column separately, we have to use both lastname and firstname as a tuple in comparison. I'm not interpretated it wrong in the question, I've said that separately testing is "**can't**"

Comment: @bayinamy -My apologies for reading your question too fast.  I don't have an answer about the implementation, but I added what might be a way to get the answer for specific `WHERE` clauses.  If you discover the complete answer, write an Answer and 'accept' it.